# I don't understand why this is a 'dangling' sentence

Tags: grammar, dangling-participle, dangling-modifier

I've googled some dangling modifier and sentences,
but still not sure what exactly it is.
And I don't understand why this sentence I wrote is dangling.

What I wrote was

> She went to pay admission fees and one of the staff said, "Why're choosing a major which won't make you a lot of money?", **trying to dissuade and telling her to reconsider it.**

Teacher told me the bold part is dangling and 'it' after resconsider should be removed, but I don't understand why it's a dangling sentence, because the one who 'tries to dissuade her and tells her to reconsider' is 'the staff'. Why is this a problem though the subject is same?

However I tried to change it to

> She went to pay admission fees and one of the staff tried to dissuade her and told her to reconsider. “Why’re you choosing a major which won’t make you a lot of money?”

Is there still dangling part in this sentence? Or is it correct?

Comment: What about "reconsider her choice" instead of "reconsider it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a "dangling" sentence, phrase, or clause, is one that is not a complete sentence and requires something else to make it complete.

In your example, "trying to dissuade and telling her to reconsider it" lacks a subject.  Who is doing the dissuading and telling?  Obviously, from context you mean it to be "one of the staff" but your grammar is not correct to link the two.

> ... one of the staff **tried to dissuade her** and **get her to reconsider** her major by saying, ...

This is pretty much the structure of your second sentence, which is correct.